# SVG import: How to restrict material count to the SVG's palette colors?

Tags: python, import, svg

I did an Image Trace in Adobe Illustrator and saved it as an SVG. The trace was restricted to a palette of just 6 colors. But upon importing into Blender, I end up with a separate material for each island, *which in this case is hundreds of objects* titled incrementally such as `SVGMat.820`

Up to this point, whenever I imported SVG data into Blender, it was simpler geometry, maybe a logo or something. So I just replaced the default SVG import materials with my own, maybe sampling the hex colors where relevant, and throwing away the rest.

But this time I want to keep that palette of 6 colors and just modify the shader data (I mean send unique material colors from RGB Nodes into a shared Group Node containing the shader setup - do you follow?). Unfortunately Blender has no idea that some of those materials share a common color, while others do not. And I don't feel like pasting that Group Node into 820+ separate materials! lol

Is there a way this can be tackled using Python to loop through all materials named `SVGMat.*` check if the Diffuse Color matches an existing material's Diffuse Color, and if it does, discard that redundant material in favor of the existing one?

(I feel like ideally the option to restrict materials to unique colors ought to be included as a setting of the SVG importer, possibly as default, but for now any kind of scripting workaround would be awesome.)

Comment: An easier workaround for this problem might be to just join all objects with the same color in illustrator ahead of time. Selecting them and joining them in illustrator should be relatively easy, that way when imported you only get one single material. Separating them by loose parts in Blender should also be relatively easy if you do in fact need separate objects.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I appreciate your suggestion. And it does seem like a practical idea. Unfortunately, **Join** isn't working. Illustrator gives the following error message: "The selected objects cannot be joined as they are invalid objects..." Even if they aren't in any group and are each a **<path>** by themselves. **Pathfinder: Unite** doesn't work either - it just puts the paths into groups. This is quickly turning into a gnarly Illustrator question...

Comment: Hum, not versed in illustrator myself. Try opening the svg in Inkscape and joining there, perhaps

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You convinced me to revisit Inkscape after quite some time, and I'm glad I did. Inkscape enabled me to accomplish what Illustrator could not. Steps: `1`Go to **Layer > Layers & Objects** `2`Create a layer for each color to keep paths in order. `3`Select the *topmost* layer in the stack, then **Edit > Select Same... Fill Color**, and drag those selected paths into the *topmost* Layer. `4`Repeat step 3, selecting the topmost path, but move to the next layer down. Do this for ea. color. `5`For ea. Layer, select the range of all paths inside, then **Path > Union** `6`Save As

Comment: I'd say that deserves an answer. Could you post it below with a few screenshots of the result? Feel free to ping me in the comments for an upvote.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks. :-) Do you think it's better to post the answer here for the sake of resolving this question, or to post a new question + answer in Graphic Design SE? I was sort of wondering what to do with this since it turned out that the solution involves software other than Blender.

Comment: Using other software is fine here if it solves the issue, as long as it focuses on a Blender related problem. You may also consider posting there as well for the Inkscape part at least, I'm not a frequent visitor there, so not sure about the on-topicness, but at least initially it seems fine. haven't used it much lately, but Inkscape matured quite well lately, especially the multi-page support.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've posted an answer - something a little more comprehensive than the explanation in my comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting with a muli-path trace result created with some vector design software such as Illustrator or Inkscape - here are the steps in Inkscape for consolidating and joining the paths of that artwork according to color:

**1.** Go to **Layer > Layers & Objects**. This gets the Layers panel to appear if it isn't already visible.

[image]

**2.** Create a layer for each color to keep paths in order. To make the result more intuitive, you can re-order the layers so that *Layer 1*, *Layer 2*, *Layer 3*, etc go from top-to-bottom instead of bottom-to-top.

[image]
[image]

<sup>Tip: You can re-order layers quickly by clicking the Up and Down arrow buttons at the top of the Layers panel.</sup>

**3.** Select the topmost path in the group, then **Edit > Select Same > Fill Color**, and drag those selected paths into the topmost layer. Aim carefully to drop *into* the layer, not above or below it.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

<sup>The selected layers are now those which share the same color.</sup>

---

[image]

<sup>Tip: Once a layer contains something, a triangle icon appears to the left of it. You can use this to keep track of which layers you have already dragged paths into. It's a good idea to click this icon to collapse a layer to hide its contents after dragging paths into it.</sup>

<sup>Tip: If you have a solid color background in your trace result that you want to get rid of, now is the time to delete that path - before joining the paths by color.</sup>

**4.** Repeat step 3, selecting the topmost path, but move the selected paths to the next layer down. Do this for each path color / layer.

**5.** For each layer, select the range of all paths inside.

[image]

<sup>Note: I don't currently know of a way to select all paths in a layer in a single step, but you can select the top path and then Shift+Click the bottom path, and that whole range will be selected.</sup>

From the menu, choose Path > Union

[image]

After doing Union, rename the path to a number indicating its position in the stack.

[image]

<sup>Optional: You can drag each of these paths into a single layer to consolidate / organize. You can then delete any unused layers and groups.</sup>

[image]

**6.** You're done! Save As. This SVG is ready for import into Blender, and will now have a manageable number of paths, and materials to match.

<sub>Inkscape version used in this answer is 1.2.1 for Mac</sub>